# How can/Can I run the game Garry's Mod on Ubuntu 14 via Wine?

Tags: wine, games, steam

I have checked Google and the Wine Website. Google only gave old tips and Wine didn't say about running the game.

Is there a way I can play Garry's Mod through Wine on Linux? I don't want to download the steam version, because that means downloading all the libraries and the entire game again (and I have slow Internet). I have a fresh copy of Wine, no configurations except I set compatibility mode to Windows 98 and disabled dwrite.dll. Is there a way I can play the game through Wine?

If i join a server it crashes at Sending Client Info, and if i play singleplayer it crashes 1-2 seconds after playing a little bit.

It doesn't matter if I cant play Singleplayer. I only want to play Multiplayer. Things I've tried:

1. -dxlevel 81
2. Disabling all addons
3. Setting compatibility mode to Windows 98
4. Disabling dwrite.dll

Update:

Now it lags and crashes while playing for 3 seconds on multiplayer.

Answer (score -1):

Wine does **not** work well with games, seeing as they are complexly written. Instead you should use *PlayOnLinux*, a better alternative that's also ***free***.

Comment: I tried that. PlayOnLinux uses Wine as a base, so it still lags and crashes.

Comment: Then you can't run Garry's Mod on ubuntu. Sorry.